# Prove that a torus triangulation cannot have degrees of vertices $5, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, \ldots$

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, geometric-topology

I found one rather interesting but intractable topology problem.

> Prove that a torus triangulation cannot have degrees of vertices $5, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, \ldots$

Despite various attempts to contract the graph or reduce it to irreducible triangulation, nothing came of it.

What can you recommend?

Comment: This smells of Euler characteristic.

Comment: Do you mean it is impossible for one vertex to have degree 5, one to have degree 7 and all others to have degree 6?

Comment: Certainly the 6's cannot go on forever, as it appears they do....

Comment: «Do you mean it is impossible for one vertex to have degree 5, one to have degree 7 and all others to have degree 6?» Yes

Comment: @Neal Not sure if I am doing it right, but if $n$ is the number of vertices, then the number of edges is $e=(5+7+6(n-2))/2=3n$, and the number of faces is $f=(5+7+6(n-2))/3=2n$. Hence $n-e+f=n-3n+2n=0$. But the Euler characteristic of a torus is $0$ already. There doesn't seem to be a contradiction.

Comment: I found a triangulation of the Klein bottle in this manner, so an argument by global Euler characteristic is out of the question.

Comment: Further food for thought: for all $n \neq 1$ there is a torus triangulation with $n$ vertices of degree $7$ and $5$ each and otherwise only vertices of degree $6$.

Comment: If you want a source of a proof, I was able to find this result as the first part of the main theorem in a paper titled 'On the toroidal analogue of Eberhard's Theorem', by S. Jendrol and E. Jucovic (there are accents on the last letters of each name).

The proof is two pages of research math with a complicated multi-faceted argument and two diagrams, so your best bet may be to read the paper if you are curious about the proof.

Comment: There is also a proof in the paper 'There is no triangulation of the torus with
vertex degrees 5, 6, . . . , 6, 7 and related results: Geometric proofs for combinatorial theorems', by Izmestiev et. al.

Comment: @BrandonduPreez: An answer providing those two references would be good. I took a look at the first one, it looks nice. It's published as Jendrol', S.; Jucovič, E.
On the toroidal analogue of Eberhard's theorem. Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 25 (1972), 385–398

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a proof, but I'll post some references. 
The problem is a research-level one for sure, and looks a bit too involved for a post here.

The proof that such a triangulation is impossible is the content of the first part of the main proof in *On the toroidal analogue of Eberhard's Theorem*, by Jendrol and Jucovič, Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 25 (1972), 385–398 (Thank-you to Lee Mosher for finding a full citation).

Effectively, the main theorem shows that the degree sequences of the form 5, 6, ... 6, 7 are the *only* degree sequences that 'work' with the Euler Characteristic which are *not* degree sequences of toroidal polyhedra.

If you prefer a different flavor proof via holonomy (?), you may be interested in *There is no triangulation of the torus with vertex degrees 5, 6, . . . , 6, 7 and related results: Geometric proofs for combinatorial theorems*, by Izmestiev, Kusner, Rote, Springborn and Sullivan.